# How were Professor X, Magneto, Wolverine and Storm surviving the Sentinels?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In *X-Men: Days of the Future Past* movie, there was no solution against Sentinels other than changing the past. Also, Sentinels were very smart in searching mutants.

Team of Professor X (in the X-jet) didn't have any mutant who had control over time by any way. How did they survive so far (before coming to the remote monastery of the movie)?

Comment: My impression was that they managed it by hiding in a remote monastery. Because once the Sentinels found them there, they didn’t survive very long. (Spoilers.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite They came to monastery from somewhere else.

Comment: Yup. Maybe there weren’t any Sentinels in the place where they came from.

Comment: I would just like to add, we haven't really seen a maximum limit to Wolverine's powers in the films. Maybe he *didn't* survive the Sentinels, but then he got better.

Answer (score 3):

The Sentinels got progressively upgraded to the point we see in Dofp. They started off as simple robots, that any number of average mutants could destroy. As we saw, even the strongest Sentinels seen can be taken down by strong mutants working together in creative ways. And using Kitty's power fairly early would help any resistance. But we know that the progression of Sentinels has lead to mutants being picked off one by one until only a handle are left. At that point, hundreds were sent to kill the strongest mutants left alive.

Comment: When did you see the first version of Sentinels? The androids near White House weren't Sentinels. At that point, Mystique wasn't captured for research.

Comment: You think those androids weren't Sentinels?

Comment: Let's say, they were Sentinels by brand. Do you have any reference that powerful mutants were able to defeat Sentinels after Mystique's power was harnessed?

Comment: Yes, every Sentinel we see destroyed on screen. They are not invincible, just really dangerous and overpowered. Also in every single medium that Sentinels have been shown, they get better as time goes on. The mystique Sentinels are the movie version of the unstoppable Sentinel, Nimrod from the future.

Comment: I mean, Trask called them "Sentinels" in 1973...